# Please avoid trivial edits during Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winterbash, winterbash-2015

We all love the hats,* and we covet the fashionable scarf of the [Timey Wimey hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey).

But please, make edits that you would be proud of during the rest of the year. Edits should be, as always, either substantial improvements to the post or otherwise be important.

Trivial edits on old questions not only make the baby hats cry, but also threaten the integrity of the time streams.

<sup>* Apart from our resident hat-haters.**</sup>
<sup>** May not actually hate hats.</sup>

Comment: worth trivially-editing this to bump it for the new year?

Comment: @nitsua60 It was featured last year; it might be worth doing that again, but I don't (yet?) see any hat that would encourage trivial edits. Is there one I'm overlooking?

Comment: I only thought of it because I made three quick edits to old posts in doing some research on Elementary/Taco. (I took a while to find non-trivial ones to make, but between that and answering a few questions today, I was seeing a lot of sheep on the frontpage....)

Comment: @nitsua60 Normal behaviour, then. :) If we get a plague of small edits we can [featured] this again, but I think we can afford to be reactive with this year's crop of hats.